# To implement a different login systems in a single page for Frappe ERPNext?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, frameworks, erpnext, frappe

To implement a dual login system for Frappe ERPNext where administrators log in with email and password and customers log in with a mobile number OTP is it possible ? Thanks in Advance

how to bypass a 2 urls in a single page for example 127.0.0.1:8000/Admin login
and  127.0.0.1:8000/customer login here for admin login is login with email and password
and customer is login with mobile number otp give me a step by step process of frappe ERP next
we are expecting 2 urls are merge in single.